# Moving an entire row to another sheet with condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a script to move entire row in Google sheet to another sheet in the same spreadsheet/workbook, when column N is "MOVETHIS".

I am using a script like this:

```
function MoveToSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SOURCE");
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 14, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var moveRows = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[0] == "MOVETHIS") ar.push(i + 1);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DESTINATION");
  moveRows.forEach(function(e) {
    sheet.getRange(e, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  });
  moveRows.reverse().forEach(function(e) {sheet.deleteRow(e)});
}
```

At first it was actually working, but then it stopped working.

Maybe better to use another script or maybe best to fix the currect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function MoveToSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SOURCE");
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("DESTINATION")
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const o = vs.map(r => (r[13] == "MOVETHIS") ? r : '').filter(r => r !== '');
  if(o && o.length>0) {
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
  }
}
```

SOURCE:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 | COL21 | COL22 | COL23 | COL24 | COL25 | COL26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 11 | 3 | 15 | 6 | 13 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 3 | 11 | 15 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 18 | 7 | 16 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 7 | 19 | 7 | 2 | 3 | MOVETHIS | 18 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 6 | 18 | 3 | 11 | 13 | 14 | 4 | 8 |
| 13 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 17 | 3 | 16 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 7 | 16 | 2 | 11 | 10 | 8 | 13 | 6 | 9 | 13 | 14 | 19 | 9 | 19 | 5 |
| 5 | 18 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 16 | 3 | 4 | 10 | 2 | 14 | 19 | 13 | MOVETHIS | 11 | 6 | 13 | 19 | 19 | 13 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 5 | 19 | 11 |
| 18 | 10 | 14 | 7 | 15 | 0 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 0 | 15 | 17 | 15 | 7 | 15 | 2 | 13 | 15 | 11 | 0 | 12 | 19 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 9 |
| 14 | 12 | 19 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 18 | 2 | 7 | 7 | 10 | 11 | 9 | MOVETHIS | 1 | 3 | 10 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 15 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 8 |
| 14 | 14 | 17 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 19 | 5 | 18 | 3 | 5 | 16 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 18 | 10 | 18 | 15 | 14 | 8 | 5 | 17 | 18 | 12 |
| 17 | 7 | 3 | 8 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 1 | 11 | 8 | 14 | 9 | 2 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 3 | 7 | 19 | 8 | 7 | 17 | 16 | 4 | 10 | 16 | 16 |
| 14 | 10 | 5 | 17 | 1 | 8 | 15 | 16 | 6 | 13 | 6 | 17 | 18 | 2 | 16 | 19 | 14 | 6 | 12 | 15 | 12 | 19 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 14 |
| 1 | 7 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 18 | 16 | 11 | 13 | 2 | 9 | 13 | 14 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 8 | 1 | 19 | 12 | 3 | 7 | 7 | 6 | 16 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 16 | 16 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 6 | 10 | 11 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 8 | 3 | 4 | 13 | 18 | 18 | 14 | 7 | 4 | 6 | 17 | 1 |
| 9 | 17 | 13 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 7 | 3 | 19 | 9 | 6 | MOVETHIS | 9 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 7 | 1 | 14 | 13 | 16 | 6 | 12 |
| 10 | 6 | 16 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 14 | 4 | 17 | 0 | 5 | 17 | 10 | 10 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 12 | 7 | 1 | 6 | 9 | 15 | 6 | 15 |
| 8 | 16 | 13 | 10 | 8 | 18 | 9 | 1 | 18 | 13 | 11 | 12 | 12 | MOVETHIS | 8 | 16 | 16 | 13 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 1 | 8 | 10 | 15 | 2 |
| 0 | 8 | 12 | 5 | 12 | 13 | 12 | 5 | 8 | 11 | 16 | 19 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 8 | 19 | 8 | 1 | 7 | 13 | 9 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 19 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 6 | 13 | 19 | 0 | 17 | 15 | 15 | 4 | MOVETHIS | 8 | 3 | 13 | 5 | 16 | 17 | 9 | 15 | 12 | 8 | 13 | 1 |
| 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 11 | 5 | 14 | 11 | 8 | 11 | 12 | 3 | 16 | 5 | 16 | 2 | 4 | 17 | 16 | 10 | 7 | 14 | 9 | 0 | 7 |
| 17 | 17 | 15 | 11 | 0 | 3 | 15 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 4 | 4 | 10 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 13 | 1 | 4 | 16 | 5 | 16 | 14 | 11 | 8 | 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 19 | 18 | 0 | 14 | 4 | 11 | 19 | 10 | 12 | 13 | 4 | 15 | 16 | 0 | 12 | 19 | 19 | 3 | 9 | 5 | 9 | 6 | 15 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | 19 | 19 | 4 | 7 | 16 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 16 | 10 | MOVETHIS | 18 | 2 | 3 | 13 | 14 | 10 | 11 | 13 | 7 | 17 | 17 | 8 |

DESTINATION:

| 7 | 5 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 7 | 19 | 7 | 2 | 3 | MOVETHIS | 18 | 4 | 4 | 14 | 6 | 18 | 3 | 11 | 13 | 14 | 4 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 18 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 16 | 3 | 4 | 10 | 2 | 14 | 19 | 13 | MOVETHIS | 11 | 6 | 13 | 19 | 19 | 13 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 5 | 19 | 11 |
| 14 | 12 | 19 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 18 | 2 | 7 | 7 | 10 | 11 | 9 | MOVETHIS | 1 | 3 | 10 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 15 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 8 |
| 17 | 7 | 3 | 8 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 1 | 11 | 8 | 14 | 9 | 2 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 3 | 7 | 19 | 8 | 7 | 17 | 16 | 4 | 10 | 16 | 16 |
| 1 | 7 | 11 | 10 | 11 | 18 | 16 | 11 | 13 | 2 | 9 | 13 | 14 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 8 | 1 | 19 | 12 | 3 | 7 | 7 | 6 | 16 | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | 17 | 13 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 15 | 7 | 3 | 19 | 9 | 6 | MOVETHIS | 9 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 7 | 1 | 14 | 13 | 16 | 6 | 12 |
| 8 | 16 | 13 | 10 | 8 | 18 | 9 | 1 | 18 | 13 | 11 | 12 | 12 | MOVETHIS | 8 | 16 | 16 | 13 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 1 | 8 | 10 | 15 | 2 |
| 1 | 19 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 6 | 13 | 19 | 0 | 17 | 15 | 15 | 4 | MOVETHIS | 8 | 3 | 13 | 5 | 16 | 17 | 9 | 15 | 12 | 8 | 13 | 1 |
| 17 | 17 | 15 | 11 | 0 | 3 | 15 | 16 | 15 | 14 | 4 | 4 | 10 | MOVETHIS | 10 | 13 | 1 | 4 | 16 | 5 | 16 | 14 | 11 | 8 | 7 | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | 19 | 19 | 4 | 7 | 16 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 16 | 10 | MOVETHIS | 18 | 2 | 3 | 13 | 14 | 10 | 11 | 13 | 7 | 17 | 17 | 8 |

Comment: I get this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I guess you did not have any "MOVETHIS's"

Comment: There are 3 MOVETHIS in column N: https://app.screencast.com/vVzdvLYMfhOiD

Comment: I just tested it myself and it works for me.  I have the MOVETHIS in column N

Comment: I'm not familiar with that URL so I'm not going to  follow it

Comment: Are you sure you don't have spaces in there?